# When using multiple GPUs in Tensorflow, network variables on GPU or CPU?

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I am using multiple GPUs. I found that basically using multiple GPUs is declaring a network each device with shared weights.

Then, the weights are actually sitting on the first GPU(`/gpu:0`) and shared with the remaining GPUs, which I made sure using Tensorboard. Following is the codes.

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for gid in range(num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % gid):
            with tf.name_scope('tower%s' % gid) as scope:
                net = Net(...)
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

Is it totally okay? Or in the `Net` definition, should I explicitly declare each weight (e.g., convolution layer weight) in `/cpu:0`?

In `CIFAR10` multiple GPU example, they declare weights in CPU and share them with multiple GPUs, as in

```
kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],...)
biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
# _variable_with_weight_decay() and _variable_on_cpu explcitly() CPU
```

Why is it? Is there a reason?

Comment: Does the `Net` method create a new net each time ? Would you be able to share its implementation?

Comment: Yes. You should create weight variables with `tf.get_variable()` and NOT with `tf.Variable()`. Then, when using `reuse`, you will share weight variables. You can see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope

Comment: So the problem was indeed that you created a new model in each occurence of the for loop, wasn't it?

Comment: Oh, my question was whether I should explicitly declare weights on CPU and share them multiple GPUs (as in the CIFAR10 tutorial), or it is enough to declare weights on the first GPU and share them with the rest GPUs (as in the example I showed). I am curious if it matters and how different in terms of performance. Why does the tutorial do so?

Comment: @YWPKwon Have you solved the problem? I wonder if the weights on CPU can speed up the model training.